# Rake TestTask won't run Unit Tests

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rake, testunit

my rake TestTask looks like this

```
Rake::TestTask.new(:tasks) do |t|
  t.libs << "test"
  t.test_files = FileList['tasks/tasks*.rb']
  t.verbose = true
end
```

My unit test named tasks01.rb looks like this

```
require_relative '../../class_based_page_objects/tasks/add_task'
require_relative '../../class_based_page_objects/tasks/tasks_grid_view'
require_relative '../../helpers/ssh_test_session'
require_relative '../../class_based_page_objects/login'

require "test-unit"
gem "test-unit"
require "selenium-webdriver"

puts "Will you print this?"

class Task01Test < Test::Unit::TestCase

  def setup
    #test Setup goes here 
    puts "Setup"
  end

  def test_assign_to_not_real_user
    # Test goes here 
    puts "Test"
  end
end
```

When I

```
rake tasks
```

I get

```
"Will you print this?"
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Which version of testunit are you using? the `gem "test-unit"` bit, I believe is from an older version.

Comment: @ChrisVo test-unit (2.5.5)

Comment: I doesn't make sense to `require test-unit` and define afterwords which gem you want. In your case there is no difference, it is the newest installed version used, but you should change the sequence.

Answer (score 0):

You just need a description line in your Rakefile code, like so:

```
desc "A description here without a period"
Rake::TestTask.new(:tasks) do |t|
  t.libs << "test"
  t.test_files = FileList['tasks/tasks*.rb']
  t.verbose = true
end
```